# Understanding Surfaces Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, spatial, hololens

I'm using Hololens with Spatial Mapping and Spatial Understanding. I know that for finding surfaces (wall, floor etc) I can use Raycast, but I'd like to know if there is another method. I was thinking that when the collider of the gameobject collides with the mesh of such surfaces, I can obtain the surface name through `OnTriggerEnter`, but how can I get the surface's type (ceiling etc)? I'm using holotoolkit.

Answer (score 0):

Spatial Understanding has been deprecated several years ago in favor of [Scene Understanding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/scene-understanding). If your need isn't specifically for HoloLens 1st gen, The Scene Understanding SDK of HoloLens 2 provided a high-level abstract representation of your unstructured environment and the [SceneObject Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/scene-understanding-sdk#sceneobject-enumeration) feature which can meet your need.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say the I'm using Hololens 1st gen.  Do you have any suggestions?